# SimpleXML load String puting the values into Array() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have a XML in form of String (after XLS transform):

```
<course>
    <topic>
        <chapter>Some value</chapter>
        <title>Some value</title>
        <content>Some value</content>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <chapter>Some value</chapter>
        <title>Some value</title>
        <content>Some value</content>
    </topic>
    ....
</course>
```

Then I'm pushing above mentioned XML into the Array():

```
$new_xml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($new_xml);
$root = $xml2->xpath("//topic");

$current = 0;
$topics_list = array();

// put the xml values into multidimensional array
foreach($root as $data) {
    if ($data === 'chapter') {
        $topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = $data->chapter;
    }
    if ($data === 'title') {
        $topics_list[$current]['title'] = $data->title;
    }
    if ($data === 'content') {
        $topics_list[$current]['content'] = $data->content;
    }
    $current++;
}
print_r($topics_list);
```

**Problem:** Result is empty array. I've tried **string** like:

```
$topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = (string) $data->chapter;
```

but result is still empty. Can anyone explain, where is my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because my topic element has only simple child elements and not attributes, I can cast it to array and add it to the list ([Demo](http://eval.in/26406)):

```
$xml2 = SimpleXMLElement($new_xml);
$topics_list = array();
foreach ($xml2->children() as $data) {
    $topics_list[] = (array) $data;
}
```

The alternative method is to map [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) on the topic elements ([Demo](http://eval.in/26407)):

```
$topics_list = array_map('get_object_vars', iterator_to_array($xml2->topic, false));
```

But that might become a bit hard to read/follow. Foreach is probably more appropriate.

---

And here is the first working version of my code:

```
$xml2 = SimpleXMLElement($new_xml);
$current = 0;
$topics_list = array();
foreach($xml2->children() as $data) {
    $topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = (string) $data->chapter;
    $topics_list[$current]['title'] = (string) $data->title;
    $topics_list[$current]['content'] = (string) $data->content;
    $current++;
}
```

Thanks again to @Jack, @CoursesWeb and @fab for their investigation.

Comment: You can spare `$current` here, if you first create the array of the element and then adding it - in your case this does not even need any additional variable. I added one (and a half) example to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you not get the name of the xml element.

To get the name of the xml element, apply `elm->getName()`

In your code should be:

```
if ($data->getName() === 'chapter')
```

For more details about traversing and getting xml elements with Simplexml, see this tutorial: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-simplexml

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes.

**1. return value of xpath()**

```
$root = $xml2->xpath("//topic");
```

Here you assign `$root` to a list of all nodes retrieved by the XPath `//topic`. So, when you iterate over it with

```
foreach($root as $data)
```

$data refers to each of the `<topic>` elements, not the children of those.

**2. comparison of SimpleXMLElements with strings**

Let's assume, you loop over the right elements and `$data` refers to the `<chapter>` element: then the following expressions are true:

```
$data == 'Some value'
(string) $data === 'Some value'
```

But you cannot do a type safe comparison (`===`) between a SimpleXMLElement and a string, and the conversion to string does not result in the element name. What you want to do is:

```
if ($data->getName() === 'chapter')
```

**3. how to get the text value**

it should already be clear from the explanation above but you also will have to replace

```
$data->chapter
```

with

```
(string) $data
```